# Spring application context load error

Tags: spring

I am getting the below error while loading spring applicationContext.xml file. Any idea what is causing this?

```
Jan 14, 2015 10:33:27 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@e330e33: display name [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@e330e33]; startup date [Wed Jan 14 10:33:27 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/core/CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.<init>(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:86)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.<init>(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:41)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractBeanFactory.java:146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<init>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.visa.services.mtc.client.MTCWebSvcClientTest.main(MTCWebSvcClientTest.java:13)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upgrading from spring 3.2.0 to 4.1.2 with java8 env. and hibernate 3, getting exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376272/upgrading-from-spring-3-2-0-to-4-1-2-with-java8-env-and-hibernate-3-getting-ex)

Answer (score 0):

Check if all of your Spring Jars are on the same version.

Run `mvn dependency:tree` and check if all are on the same release number.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have put two Spring libraries of different versions in the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
</dependency>
```

Removing `spring-core` have worked.