# SPring AOP issue when deploying to Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have recently taken over a project and I am struggling to get it running in IntelliJ with Maven (before they used gradle and eclipse, neither of which are my favourite tools.

I really need help solving te remaining errors as google doesnt help. It did however help me fix about 15 other problems with the build/deploy process. So kudos for that.

I am using Tomcat 8.5 and maven 4.

To me it looks like something specifically to do with the AOP module. SOmething i sloading an older version and causing this error. I am put my dependency tree here

Below is the log from the apache startup

```
2022-09-12 04:57:44,962 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] [ContextLoader.java:285] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2022-09-12 04:57:45,386 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] [AbstractApplicationContext.java:510] Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Sep 12 04:57:45 CEST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
2022-09-12 04:57:45,703 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] [AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.java:228] Successfully resolved class for [com.textintegration.config.AppConfig]
2022-09-12 04:57:45,832 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] [AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.java:228] Successfully resolved class for [com.textintegration.config.WebMvcConfig]
2022-09-12 04:57:48,083 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] [RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:165] Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2022-09-12 04:57:49,130 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] [PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:309] Bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c38351d6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-09-12 04:57:49,200 WARN [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] [AbstractApplicationContext.java:487] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:220) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4763) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5232) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1775) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:291) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.82]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:291) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.82]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:152) ~[spring-aop-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:47) ~[spring-aop-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.<init>(InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:29) ~[spring-aop-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
2022-09-12 04:57:49,204 ERROR [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] [ContextLoader.java:331] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:220) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4763) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5232) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1775) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:291) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.82]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:291) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.82]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408) [na:1.8.0_221]
12-Sep-2022 04:57:49.227 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
12-Sep-2022 04:57:49.228 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/ti] startup failed due to previous errors
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:152) ~[spring-aop-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:47) ~[spring-aop-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.<init>(InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:29) ~[spring-aop-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
[2022-09-12 04:57:49,325] Artifact TextIntegration:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

I am not perfect with Spring and I am unsure what to do. There is an awful lot of files so I can't share them all here.

My [POM.xml](https://snipsave.com/user/jamiereid/snippet/gTUz98Bnren0zgE9A4/) is not shareable here as it makes the post too large and exceed the limit of the number of characters so I have saved it at [POM.xml](https://snipsave.com/user/jamiereid/snippet/gTUz98Bnren0zgE9A4/)

Here is my spring build config.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!-- Auto-detect components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.textintegration.service"/>
</beans>
```

Thank you for reading and hopefully helping me.

Comment: What is this: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;`

Comment: You can refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376946/1475228

Comment: IS there any easy way to figure out what is using that method?

I am using Spring 4.1.6-RELEASE

Comment: May be just set a break point at the starup to figure out what's wrong, also check the answers of the question I commented

Comment: I cant put a breakpiint until it deploys to tomcat properly. Or at leasst I dont think i can.

I loked at the answers on the link you provided but none solved my issue

Comment: You're using an old version of spring-batch, with a different major version to the rest of your spring depndencies, worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion checking it out now

Comment: That didnr work. You can find my dependency tree here:
https://snipsave.com/user/jamiereid/snippet/9tYbf3s26tnU4bwyWb/

Comment: `~[spring-aop-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]` ..is that in "your" tomcat? Since it's causing the exception..(..and not the version from pom!?;)

Comment: No I dont know where spring-aop-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03 comes from it isnt in my dependcies or dependency tree, maybe figureing that ourt would solve the problem

Comment: Those error can come from 2 things, either mixing jars from different versions of a framework (Spring in this case) or using incompatible versions of other libraries (like older/newer Spring Security etc). The `jersey-spring` is for Spring 2.5 you are using Spring 4.1 so those are incompatible and pulling old stuff in (and might not even work with 4.1). Spring Batch uses Spring 4.0, which should be compatible but I would recommend upgrading.

Comment: I have removed jersey spring as I only added it to try to get to the bottom of this.
I have no idea where the compatiblitiy could be, the dependency tree looks good

Comment: https://snipsave.com/user/jamiereid/snippet/dwh9VeZ83HB7Zspt5k/ dep tree here

Comment: You are now randomly updating things and makig things worse... You have now dependencies that assume Spring 5 instead of 4. So no your dependency tree doesn't look good. You have dependencies that range from Spring 4.0 to 5.2 and stuff in between and expect everything to be compatible. Your Spring Batch version was fine. I also highly doubt you still get the same error, if you do that jar is inside your tomcat and not yoru application.

Comment: I dont see anything spring related with version 5. They are all 4.1.6.RELEASE if that exists, if it doesnt they are as close to 4.1.6.RELEASE as I can get them